# jQuery access "previous" div

Tags: jquery

Here's my scenario.

I have a DIV

```
<div class="first"></div>
```

if I click on an element inside this div, it generates another div, call it

```
<div class="second"></div>
```

now, can I click on an element inside second div to access the first div? does second DIV know that the first div exists?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do, may be you need different logic.

Comment: Please clarify that. You can always query from any point any element. Especially if they have ids or classnames: `$('.first')`.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can use .prev().

http://api.jquery.com/prev/

So, from a child of "second", you can do something like:
$(this).parent("second").prev()